# Highcharts, use images to show columns in column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, frontend

I'd like to make a chart with images as columns in Highcharts like [this coffee bean example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPnT1.png) in  [the Highcharts documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/pictorial)

However, the Highchart version we are using is older and does not support the pictorial chart. Is there a way to use column chart to create the same result?

I have tried using column chart with patternfill but it doesn't show up properly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to create such a chart without the pictorial feature. As you mentioned, you can use the `pattern-fill` module, but you need to take care of the image distribution.

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 10,
      color: {
        pattern: {
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          image: 'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png'
        }
      }
    }, ...],
    type: 'column',
    ...
  }]
```

Another way is to use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer.image`, and add images in front of columns. Similar to in this SO thread: [Apply Background Image to A Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521089/apply-background-image-to-a-column)

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nrzjovug/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/pattern-fills